# shared memory in C memory fault

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared

I have been searching here but cannot find a solution.

In the C (linux) code below I'm trying to read strings from a txt to a buffer and copy that buffer to the buffer array in the struct so I can read from the client.

The problem is that when im trying to do the strcpy it says "memory fault". I commentted it at "HERE" is in the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main() {

  FILE *fp;

  char buff[255];
  int i;
  int shmid;

  typedef struct structStr {
    char buffer[100][255];
    int numCol;
  } structure;

  // ftok to generate unique key
  key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65);

  // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
  shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(structure), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
  // shmat to attach to shared memory
  structure *input = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

  fp = fopen("entrada.txt", "r");

  i = 0;

  while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), (FILE *)fp)) {
    printf("i = %d ", i);
    printf("buff: %s", buff);
    strcpy(input->buffer[i], buff); //HERE
    // printf("buffer[%d]: %s", i, input->buffer[i]);
    i++;
  }

  input->numCol = i;

  // detach from shared memory
  shmdt(input);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

the output is:
i = 0 buff: a1
Memory fault

PD: my txt has :

a1
a2
a3
.
.
.
a30

thats why is printing a1 only